# How can I remove members from TFS groups programmatically in c#?

Tags: tfs

I have access to TFS users. I can get them into list but need to remove some of them from all the groups in our TFS. I've done so many researchers so far. Simply, **I need to remove user from TFS groups.**

I am open to any suggestions. Even for the crazy ones!

I've tried programmatical stuff. Don't have any clue.

After so many tries, finally got somewhere. My final code:

```
bool isError = false;
TeamFoundationIdentity memberId = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName, id.DisplayName, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
IIdentityManagementService2 ims2 = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService2>();
string group = "Confidential Group;
 
TeamFoundationIdentity groupId = ims2.ReadIdentity(group);

if (groupId == null)
{
    isError = true;
}

if (memberId == null)
{
    isError = true;
}

if (!isError)
{
    ims2.RemoveMemberFromApplicationGroup(groupId.Descriptor, memberId.Descriptor);
}
```

The error:

```
'TF50621: The Team Foundation group that you wish to manage is not owned by service host TEAM FOUNDATION, it is owned by . Please target your request at the correct host.'**
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove a user from an (azure) active directory domain group. You can't do that with the TFS API'

Comment: Can you show the values you're entering here? Or add a breakpoint or a couple of additional checks to better understand what you're actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Azure Boards Team Tools](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-boards-team-tools/blob/main/TfsTeams%20CmdLine/TeamWrapper.cs#L211).

It does most of what you need already:

```
message = string.Empty;
bool ret = true;
TeamFoundationTeam t = this.teamService.ReadTeam(this.projectInfo.Uri, team, null);
TeamFoundationIdentity i = this.identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, user, MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

if (t == null)
{
    message = "Team [" + team + "] not found";
    ret = false;
}

if (i == null)
{
    message = "User [" + user + "] not found";
    ret = false;
}

if (ret)
{
    this.identityManagementService.RemoveMemberFromApplicationGroup( t.Identity.Descriptor, i.Descriptor);
    message = "User removed ";
}

return ret;
```

This function removes a user from a Team. A Team is a special kind of group, the function is easy to adapt to retrieve a Group to delete the user from though:

Replace

```
TeamFoundationTeam t = this.teamService.ReadTeam(this.projectInfo.Uri, team, null);
```

With:

```
string group = ...
var t = this.identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(group);
```

Or [use the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/remove-member-from-group?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) :

```
DELETE https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members/{memberId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your contribution!

I got really close. Now I am getting this error:

'TF56044: The identity you are attempting to edit is not an application group.' What does it mean actually? 
It appears when I run the method "RemoveMemberFromApplicationGroup" 
Do I need to edit group or something?

Comment: Please share *your* code.

Comment: You can edit your Q and add the new information. No need to add big *update* or *added* banners. Just rewrite your Q with the information you have so far.

Comment: When removing a member from a group, that method receives the Group's identity descriptor and the User's identity descriptor. It looks like the first parameter you're passing is not a group that's managed by Azure DevOps. Is it an Azure Active Directory group by any chance? You can't manage those through the APIs in Azure DevOps, you'd need to go through AAD instead.